# Install Specific Qemu

Tags: apt, qemu

When I do `apt install qemu` it gives all cpu flavors and all the extra things I don't really use. I wonder if there is a way to just install `qemu-system-x86_64`.

Comment: What do you mean with "It gives all cpu flavors"? On my 19.04 system, it is just one package, no dependencies, that gets installed.

Comment: They probably mean that the meta package [qemu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/qemu) depends on [qemu-system](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/qemu-system) which in turn installs binaries for all supported platforms. @Adminy you could try installing all dependencies of `qemu` except `qemu-system` and install only `qemu-system-x86_64`, but I'm not sure if that will work.

Comment: @Jos on 18.04, I see "The following additional packages will be installed: binfmt-support qemu-slof qemu-system qemu-system-arm qemu-system-mips qemu-system-misc qemu-system-ppc qemu-system-s390x qemu-system-sparc qemu-user qemu-user-binfmt"

Comment: @DKBose Funny. I had none of these installed on my 19.04 system. Installing just `qemu` didn't pull them in either. On my 18.04 system, it pulled in all of these and more.

Comment: @Jos I already use `qemu-kvm` which maybe why I see fewer new packages to be installed than you (in 18.04)?

Comment: Look at all this diversity ... thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing `qemu` is all of it - the system virtualization and the user mode emulation of all arches.
From the package description:

> - User mode emulation ...
> - Full system emulation ...

The next lesser set would be `qemu-system` which will depend on all system emulations but no user mode emulation.
From the package description:

> This metapackage provides the full system emulation binaries for all
>   supported  targets, by depending on all per-architecture system
>   emulation packages which  QEMU supports.

And finally if you just want x86 system emulation you can install just `qemu-system-x86`

```
# apt install qemu-system-x86 Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done The following
additional packages will be installed:   ipxe-qemu
ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms qemu-block-extra qemu-system-common
qemu-system-data qemu-system-gui qemu-utils seabios sharutils
Suggested packages:   samba vde2 sgabios ovmf debootstrap
sharutils-doc bsd-mailx | mailx The following NEW packages will be
installed:   ipxe-qemu ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms qemu-block-extra
qemu-system-common qemu-system-data qemu-system-gui qemu-system-x86
qemu-utils seabios sharutils
```